# how to switch off nodejs utilities debug

Tags: node.js, debugging

after some time, the code is filled with quite some require('utilities').debug('abc').

how to turn it off during the production since it will slow down my app a lot. I expect it is watching some global environment, but cannot find any doc.

/Eric

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a proper way of disabling [`util.debug`](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_debug_string) output.

The best advice I can get you is to switch to [`debug` module](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug), written by [TJ Holowaychuk](https://github.com/tj).

Meanwhile, you may disable `util.debug` output in production simply by redefining it with an empty function, e.g.:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  require('util').debug = function() {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would still recommend to put additional conditions into code for each debug output statement. Like

```
if (config.debug) { /* do debug output */ }
```

Overriding built-in function (as Leonid Beschastny suggested), in my opinion, is very bad idea and can lead to conflicts in third party modules.